# How to convert boolean to int in itemarray using datatable?

Tags: c#, datatable

How I convert `boolean` value to int (1 for `True` and 2 for `false`) inside `ItemArray`. Below is function for converting `DataTable` to csv.

```
public  string ToCSV(DataTable tbl, Boolean ColumnHeader)
    {
        string FinalResult = string.Empty;
        StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();

        if (ColumnHeader == true)
        {
            //column headers
            strb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", tbl.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                .Select(s => "\"" + s.ColumnName + "\"")));
        }
        //rows
        tbl.AsEnumerable().Select(s => strb.AppendLine(
           string.Join(",", s.ItemArray.Select(
               i => "\"" + i.ToString() + "\"")))).ToList();
        FinalResult = strb.ToString();
        strb= null;
        return FinalResult; 
        //return strb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: You could write an extendion method for `bool` called e.g. `ToInt()` and retruning an `int`

Comment: The boolean column containing True /false value in datatable.

Comment: Use BitConverter.ToBoolean

Comment: The `strb= null;` line is a holdover from how things used to work in the vb6/vbscript era. It's no longer useful or helpful, and in rare cases can actually be harmful to your code.

Comment: @MusakkhirSayyed Are you going to accept the answer i gave? if not exlpain why my answer does not solve the problem so we can think of a different solution for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<bool> data = new List<bool>() { true, false, false, true };
List<int> intdata = data.Select(x => x ? 1 : 2).ToList();
```

if you are receiving the true or false as string you can simple change the if statement
 from `x ? 1: 2` to `x == "true" ? 1 : 2`